# ESLint: Parsing error: Unknown compiler option 'noUncheckedIndexedAccess'

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, tsconfig

I changed the configuration of my `tsconfig.json` file of a node project as following and now it is giving `ESLint: Parsing error: Unknown compiler option 'noUncheckedIndexedAccess'` error.

[image: ESLint Error]

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "lib",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "target": "es2018",
      "typeRoots": [
          "node_modules/@types"
      ],
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "lib": [
          "es2017",
          "dom"
      ],
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: What are the versions of typescript and eslint?

Comment: `eslint` version is 7.6.0 and `typescript` version is 3.8.0

Comment: ` noUncheckedIndexedAccess` is available from typescript 4.1

Comment: The error is now gone after updating typescript, thanks @HTN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As HTN pointed out in his comment, `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` is available since 4.1. The [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) confirm this.

As a result, this is the problematic line:

```
"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
```

your Typescript 3.8.0 is older than the feature it attempts to use, hence the error. You can either go with the current Typescript you have, but removing that line or you could upgrade Typescript to at least 4.1 version. Both approaches would solve the issue, but Typescript version upgrade is generally considered to be a better approach as it will provide new options for you, instead of you having to restrict access to features.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the latest version of typescript solves the problem

```
npm i typescript@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

"I encountered a similar issue, particularly at the start of the file during the imports. The solution for me was to update the version of ESLint being used. I initially had `"eslint": "^8.33.0"` in my package.jsoin, but updating it to a newer version `"eslint": "^8.41.0"` resolved the problem.

`"eslint": "^8.33.0" -> "eslint": "^8.41.0"`